# If someone says "That hair tho", does it have a positive or a negative meaning?

Tags: slang, colloquial-language, connotations

I've seen this many times on social media and I can't decide whether it has good or bad meaning.

[Here is an example from twitter](https://twitter.com/BullittCapital/status/1588261645175836672) of a picture of a person with the statement saying

> BREAKING: CANTOR GETS TOO CLEVER. (That hair tho…)

However the person's hair looks neutral to me and so it's hard to tell if this is a positive or negative statement.

Comment: Are you sure? "That X though" relates to a previous idea.

Comment: @Lambie No it doesn't.. it was written like this

Comment: tho is a slang way to write **though**, the adverb or conjunction.

Comment: Sounds negative and kind of judgmental in a young-teen way. Nice face, but that hair tho (though). Like the sexist 'nice legs, shame about the face' that men used to say about women in Britain when I was younger.

Comment: @Lambie yes I already know this, but it's also used as a slang expression (I guess)

Comment: The previous idea could be implied [He or she mostly looks nice but] that hair though.

Comment: So it has a negative meaning!!

Comment: Those shoes though! That accent though! Those political views though! I wouldn't like people to talk about me like that.

Comment: I think it depends heavily on the context.

Comment: @stangdon Any example for both caces?

Comment: First thing to do is to link to the quotes on social media. It is bad to say "I've seen this a lot" but not provide any examples of the language in context.  You can edit your post to include links.

Comment: It is not slang, per se. It means except.  I love your dress and shoes. That hair though [is something I think is awful]. It's an unfinished phrase.

Comment: It can have a positive meaning too, as a way of pointing out the hair (completely disregarding everything else). It the "tho" there *is* slang, and doesn't necessarily have meaning in context, it's just a phrase.

Comment: @Lambie It is slang, and it seems like you are trying to interpret the phrase according to its literal English meaning rather than its slang meaning. The "tho" or "doe" in "That X tho" does not convey the literal meaning of the English word "though."

Comment: @d_b You are very mistaken. though and through are spelled tho and thru all the time. See this entry in Merriam Webster: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tho//These are informal spellings. Their current use occurs chiefly in informal writing (as in personal letters) and in some technical journals. And doe it is not. That's for sure. See James K's answer below.

Comment: @Lambie I'm not so sure how familiar you are with Internet culture in general, but "tho" and "doe" *do* have the same meaning in "that hair tho/doe" and neither of them is intended to be a shortened version of "though" (even though that's where they came from)

Comment: @Lambie found this https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/64323/evolution-noun-though

Comment: @Esther Pretty good article. :) Sounds like it's kinda sayin' what I was saying re dat and doe.

Comment: @Lambie definitely does come from AAVE, but it seems to have been "adopted" by the Internet at large ;)

Answer (score 8):

It depends heavily on context; however this is a common slang expression "That ___ tho" which is used to *draw attention toward* something which may or may not even have a "good or bad meaning".

For example,

These are pointing out "that hair tho" surrounded by context which provides a **positive** outlook:

- https://twitter.com/mia110605/status/1586731204153602048
- https://twitter.com/KnailBiter/status/1587130628801236996
- https://twitter.com/Locixx_/status/1586643543309037569

These are more obviously broken up as "[look at] that hair tho" followed by the actual reaction

- https://twitter.com/TsundereMew/status/1587075855158681602
- https://twitter.com/AnjiRae17/status/1584856814067548166

But even further, here is an example of neither good nor bad but a "don't know how I feel about it but look at that hair tho"

- https://twitter.com/TBHWW22/status/1586796725943300096

Finally, I'd note that contrary to "though" seeming to imply a negative light, "Dat tho" is

> often used in online conversations to place a positive emphasis on a particular aspect or feature within a story, image or video that has been shared online.

The modern slang expression has roots in internet meme culture which used to more commonly be seen as "Dat ___ doe". https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/dat-tho

Comment: It is NOT slang. It points to an unfinished thought.

Comment: @Lambie not really, "that X tho" can just mean "look at that X".

Comment: @ccchoy This is exactly what I wanted to know!! Thanks alot :)

Comment: It can also mean: That hair though ( really don't like it). It's idiomatic and colloquial but not slang.

Comment: @Lambie the expression and usage examples("social media" in the question) are generally either online or younger generations and while there is some meaning which derives from the language's formal roots with "though", I think the expression's meaning evolved from online meme culture - https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/64323/evolution-noun-though. Years ago, you'd see similar expressions like "Dat __ doe" https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/dat-tho or  https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dat%20%5Bblank%5D%20doe

Comment: Interestingly, a lot of "That ___ tho" I see are more approving/positive than they are negative nowadays, but again it could go either way depending on context.

Comment: It doesn't matter that younger people use it. It has been used for ages and ages by all ages. And it basically means: but I don't like some x. dat x doe is not relevant and anyway, that's just AAVE.

Comment: @Lambie that's not the case though. In this context it does *not* necessarily have a negative connotation, and tho/doe are interchangeable in "Internet/meme culture English"

Comment: @Esther  Well, it's been around since way before the Internet. And doe is Black English. [sigh] And was just picked up on by internet users. And dat and doe is AAVE. All use of dat is. That's where it comes from. Like: Dat's dat shit. For example: https://genius.com/Method-man-and-redman-dats-dat-shit-lyrics [warning: pretty heavy lyrics]

Comment: @Lambie of course that's where it *came from*, but that's not how it's used now on the Internet. Most sources familiar with Internet slang/memes conclude that it's usually positive, although it can be used both ways.

Comment: People here seem to be confusing "slang" with "conversational english." Twitter tends to use conversational norms even though it is a textual medium. Lambie is right: this is not slang.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it is used negatively most often, but there could be context that you are missing.

"Though" (or "tho'") indicates contrast.  It has a similar sense to "but".  It indicates restrictions of qualifications on what was said earlier.

> "I was hunting for work. Jobs were scarce though"  (examples and definition from Oxford dictionaries, via google)

Now if what was said before was positive, this would limit or contrast with the positive thing, and so would be negative.

> Her makeup was nice, but that hair tho' ...

However, it could qualify or contrast with a negative.

> Her makeup was crooked and awful, but that hair tho' ...

So the interpretation depends heavily on context.

Comment: Exactly and in a way, you put it at the end because you are really saying: But I don't like the hair. Her makeup was nice but I that hair though [is really bad]. For example. I do not understand why no one gets the difference between colloquial and slang.

Answer (score 1):

The expression "That X though" can be used to be positive or negative.

Traditionally, it has been almost entirely negative in the sense Michael Harvey has pointed out in a comment.

But there's also a modern usage of it, especially associated with the North American gay community, where it's highly appreciative, often in a sexualizing way.

I found these [two](https://youtu.be/fOiKXAqa_MI?t=210) [clips](https://youtu.be/NzOgOnldvTw?t=309) where it's used naturally in the modern sense of being appreciative of something sexually attractive. **Note:** They contain foul language.

So, your example of "That hair though" could be disparaging or appreciative, depending on how it's said and the context.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase itself is contrasting a positive quality with some previously described negative quality. Like, "This car has uncomfortable seats. That sound system, though, is excellent."

In the example you give, it is being used ironically. It says something negative about Mr Cantor, and then makes this contrasting positive comment about his hair. The reader is expected to understand that having a handsome hair style is trivial while being "too clever" is important, so it's a joke, not a real compliment.

(I have no idea what Mr Cantor said that was "too clever" or what point the statement is trying to make. Which is just as well because I don't want to comment on the politics, just the use of English.)